# This query gives multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query with multiple joins that gives me duplicate records....Here's my query

```
SELECT     tblB.City, tblA.ShortDesc, 
                  SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male, 
                  SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Female

FROM         tblC INNER JOIN
                  tblB ON tblC.ID = tblB.ID INNER JOIN
                  tblE ON tblC.Number = tblE.Number INNER JOIN
                  tblA ON tblE.ServiceID = tblA.ServiceID INNER JOIN
                  tblD ON tblC.IDNumber = tblC.IDNumber
WHERE     (tblA.ServiceID IN (71)) AND (tblC.Date BETWEEN '1/12/2017' AND '2/31/2017')
GROUP BY tblB.City, tblA.ShortDesc, tblD.Code
```

So this query is supposed to give me results that look like this...

```
City         Male       Female
LA           17         21
SF           23         7
```

But what I'm getting is this....

```
City         Male       Female
LA           17         0
LA           0          21
SF           23         0
SF           0          7
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening???

Comment: Doesn't seem you need to `GROUP BY tblD.Code` since you are using that in your conditional aggregate.

Comment: Where's the duplicate? Remove the code from the grouping

Comment: @ollie that did it thanks

Comment: Also you should be using ANSI date formats. The date literals you have here can be misinterpreted if the dateformat setting is not what you expect. YYYYMMDD.

Comment: And `'2/31/2017'` is not a valid date, any way that is interpreted. Not in any calendar that SQL Server can handle at least ;) I wonder what type that `tblC.Date` is ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the `GROUP BY tblD.Code` from your query:

```
SELECT 
 tblB.City, 
 tblA.ShortDesc, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Female
FROM tblC 
INNER JOIN tblB 
 ON tblC.ID = tblB.ID 
INNER JOIN tblE 
 ON tblC.ReferralNumber = tblE.ReferralNumber 
INNER JOIN tblA 
 ON tblE.ServiceID = tblA.ServiceID 
INNER JOIN tblD 
 ON tblC.IDNumber = tblMember.IDNumber
WHERE (tblA.ServiceID IN (71)) 
 AND (tblC.Date BETWEEN '2017-01-12' AND '2017-02-28')  -- there is no Feb 31
GROUP BY tblB.City, tblA.ShortDesc
```

Since you are using that column inside of your conditional aggregation, you don't need to group by it. The value of that column is most likely resulting in the multiple rows.